# How to create a hollow square (user parameters) in C# console applications?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to serious programming with a bit of experience in elementary Pascal. I am currently trying to figure out how to create a hollow square with user defined parameters in C#. I've managed to get 3 out of the 4 sides but I am out of ideas on how to manage the fourth one. This is my code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int height;
        int width;
        int counterH = 0;
        int counterW2 = 0;
        int counterW1 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the sizes of the square!");
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the height of the square.");
        height = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please input the width of the square");
        width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (counterW1 < width)
        {
            Console.Write("--");
            counterW1++;}
        Console.WriteLine();
            while (counterH < height)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("|");
                counterH++;
            }
            while (counterW2 < width)
            {
                Console.Write("--");
                counterW2++;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I would also be happy if you can suggest an easier/better/more optimised solution if you think mine is bad. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Since you can't go back up, you will have to draw the left and right sides of the square in one loop.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger; set a breakpoint on the first `while` loop and step through your code.

Comment: Experiment with this and think about how you might adapt it to your code... Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));

Comment: @MobyDisk Do I use the width counter's value to also add spaces/tabulations before the second column then?

Comment: @Ornstein Sounds logical.  Try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while (counterH < height)` loop you should loop through your width-Value and place some spaces. At the End you can place a Pipe | again.

Use `Console.Write()` and not `Console.WriteLine()` at this position, because you dont want a LineFeed / CarriageReturn after your first Pipe.

Example:

```
    while (counterH < height)
    {
        Console.Write("|");
        int counterW3 = 0;
        while (counterW3 < width)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            counterW3++;
        }
        Console.Write("|" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        counterH++;
    }
```

Comment: A good approach.  Now if you could include example code and/or explain some more (like why `Console.WriteLine()`) your answer would be better and potentially get more upvotes.

Comment: @ryanyuyu this looks like a learning excercise or school assignment so posting code would probably be going too far.  The explanation is more than detailed enough.

Comment: @MobyDisk perhaps.  I just figured this is still useful information for a newer user to keep in mind.  Also explaining the (small) difference between `Console.WriteLine()` and `Console.Write()` is still very helpful.

Comment: @DanielN That's great but can you please explain to me what System.Environment.NewLine does exactly? I tried to find something on Google, but most explanations seemed unclear.

Comment: @Ornstein The `System.Environment.NewLine` represents a linebreak and depends on your environment. On Windows it's actually "\r\n".

Comment: @DanielN I understand that it creates a new line, but I've been wondering about the nature of the comment, since I've never actually seen the Environment types. It is not necessary for you to go into explanations unless you really want to, since you already solved my problem and showed me a good way of doing it. Thank you!

Comment: @Ornstein If you would run your program under linux (with mono) it would just represent a "\n". Its just a constant which will change under different systems.